# 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk' in DRF Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my (simplified) **models.py:**

```
class MyList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='ParticipantsInList',
        related_name='participants',
    )

class ParticipantsInList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='user')
    list_parent = models.ForeignKey(MyList, related_name='list_parent')
    moderator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and my **serializers.py:**

```
class ParticipantsInListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ParticipantsInList
        exclude = ('id',)
```

and my **views.py:**

```
class ParticipantsInListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
serializer_class = ParticipantsInListSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    list_id = self.kwargs['list_pk']
    # This works:
    # return ParticipantsInList.objects.filter(list_parent=list_id)
    # While this doesn't:
    return MyList.objects.get(pk=list_id).participants.all()
```

I can't figure out why using this in views.py: ***ParticipantsInList.objects.filter(list_id=list_id)*** works, while using ***List.objects.get(pk=list_id).participants.all()*** raises an exception 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'.

I would like to use the latter because i find it better looking and also because i believe it should work..

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on exactly, but you shouldn't use `list` as a field name for model, because it's reserved as a python built in keyword. It might cause tons of issue if you do it like that.

Comment: Thanks, i've changed it now. However the issue was not related to that in this particular case. I managed to solve the problem though, if you're interested you can find the answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to serialize the through-model, which works if the query is run on the through-model itself (as was the case when *filter* was used). But when using the ManyToManyField in MyList to make the query, only the actual user object is returned. So when referencing the ManyToManyField, the solution was to use a serializer that could serialize the user object, not the through-model.

Running the queries in a shell makes this evident:

```
> ParticipantsInList.objects.filter(list_parent=1)
[<ParticipantsInList: ParticipantsInList object>, <ParticipantsInList: ParticipantsInList object>]
```

While running the other query returns:

```
> MyList.objects.get(pk=1).participants.all()
[<MyUser: user1>, <MyUser: user2>]
```

Comment: thanks, very helpful - not sure if it applies in this case, but my nested serializers needed to be called with `many=True`

Comment: Thanks @ptim, it solved my issue. Your comment was literally my last try before giving up! =))

Comment: I was staring at my serializer for a good 10 minutes before I realized thatI needed the `many=True`. Thanks, @ptim